# Issue targeting div after creating it with .wrap()

Tags: jquery, click, hidden, visible

I'm having a strange issue checking whether a div I just created with `.wrap()` is visible or not. I'm wrapping some divs and using the ID's on them as targets.  I've tested to make sure the click is actually registering with an `alert()`, and it is.

Here is the code.

```
//Leftbar jQuery
$('ul.leftnav').wrap('<div id="leftnav-wrap" class="five columns alpha" />');
$('#leftnav-wrap').prepend('<div class="arrow" />');
$('#content').has('#leftnav-wrap').find('#page').wrap('<div class="eleven columns omega" />');

//Mobile Leftbar
$('h4.mobile.toggle').click(function(){
    if ($('#leftnav-wrap').is(':hidden')){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#leftnav-wrap').addClass('active');
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('#leftnav-wrap').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Is there something inherently wrong with what I've coded?  It doesn't toggle any of the active classes it is suppose to, and I have another site that is working fine, only it's not targeting an ID just created by `.wrap()`.

JSfiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/ZD7hz](http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7hz/). Not toggling any classes

Comment: Actually what do you expect to do, there is nothing wrong in the code , the logic is wrong.Please tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: I actually just figured out what the issue is.  Posting answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here was the issue. It couldn't find a hidden div to add a class to, and it also couldn't find a visible div to remove the class from.  So clicking did nothing.

I had to preemptively hide the leftnav with CSS, and add a class for the `.active` state so it displays it again. Then, the toggling works fine...

Whoops!

Fixed jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7hz/1/